# How to create multidimensional array using input text dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-2

I have a form that adds a row to a table dynamically and I want to save the data table. My question is how to create a multidimensional array in javascript? I try this (view)

```
$( "#quot tbody" ).append(
"<tr>" +
    "<td>" + supplier.val()+ "<input type='hidden' id='_supplier'  name='data[][supplier]' value='"+ supplier.val() + "' class='form-control'> " + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + quots_number.val()+ "<input type='hidden' id='_quots_number'  name='data[][quots_number]' value='"+ quots_number.val() + "'class='form-control'> " + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + quots_date.val()+ "<input type='hidden' id='_quots_date'  name='data[][quots_date]' value='"+ quots_date.val() + "'class='form-control'> " + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + t_item_id.val()+ "<input type='hidden' id='_item_id'  name='data[][item_id]' value='"+ t_item_id.val() + "'class='form-control'> " + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + qty.val()+ "<input type='hidden' id='_qty'  name='data[][qty]' value='"+ qty.val() + "'class='form-control'> " + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + price.val()+ "<input type='hidden' id='_price'  name='data[][price]' value='"+ price.val()  + "'class='form-control'> "+ "</td>" +
    "<td>" + currency.val()+ "<input type='hidden' id='_currency'  name='data[][currency]' value='"+ currency.val()  + "'class='form-control'> "+ "</td>" +
    "<td>" + loc_id.val()+ "<input type='hidden' id='_loc_id'  name='data[][location]' value='"+ loc_id.val() + "'class='form-control'> " + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + khs_+ "<input type='hidden' id='_khs'  name='data[][khs]' value='"+ khs_  + "'class='form-control'> "+ "</td>" +
    "<td>" + util_+ "<input type='hidden' id='_util'  name='data[][utilization]' value='"+ util_  + "'class='form-control'> "+ "</td>" +
    "<td style='text-align:center;'>" +"<i onclick='removerow(this)'><span style='cursor:pointer' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></i>"+ "</td>" +
"</tr>" 
);
```

but after submit, it return null value.

this is my controller

```
if (! $_POST) {
           $dataquot = (object) $this->quot->default_value;
        } else { $table= $this->input->post('data');
            for($i = 0; $i < count($table); $i++){
                    $dataquot[$i]['supplier'] = $table[$i]['supplier'];
                    $dataquot[$i]['quots_number'] = $table[$i]['quots_number'];
                    $dataquot[$i]['quots_date'] = $table[$i]['quots_date'];
                    $dataquot[$i]['t_item_id'] = $table[$i]['t_item_id'];
                    $dataquot[$i]['qty'] = $table[$i]['qty'];
                    $dataquot[$i]['price'] = $table[$i]['price'];
                    $dataquot[$i]['currency'] = $table[$i]['currency'];
                    $dataquot[$i]['location'] = $table[$i]['location'];
                    $dataquot[$i]['khs'] = $table[$i]['khs'];
                    $dataquot[$i]['utilization'] = $table[$i]['utilization'];   
            }   

        }
```

var_dump($dataquot);

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["supplier"]=> NULL ["quots_number"]=> NULL ["quots_date"]=> NULL ["t_item_id"]=> NULL ["qty"]=> NULL ["price"]=> NULL ["currency"]=> NULL ["location"]=> NULL ["khs"]=> NULL ["utilization"]=> NULL } }
```

Thanks in advance for your kindness

Comment: What is the output of dumping $table?

Comment: @krasipenkov the output is bool(false)

Comment: So then you didn't succeed to get the POST in your controller

Comment: Try var_dump($_POST) instead of $table

Comment: this is the output of var_dump($_POST) 
    array(10) { ["supplier"]=> string(0) "" ["quots_number"]=> string(0) "" ["quots_date"]=> string(0) "" ["t_item_id"]=> string(0) "" ["qty"]=> string(0) "" ["price"]=> string(0) "" ["currency"]=> string(0) "" ["location"]=> string(0) "" ["khs"]=> string(1) "0" ["utilization"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: So the $_POST[supplier] is not an array as it is expected

Comment: What is the rest html code of this form ?

Comment: it is too long if i copy all html code here, there are only form_input,submit button, and header of the table. Then how to create an array, is it above correct? `name = data[][supplier]`

Comment: `name = data[][supplier]` should be ok. But is the form html so big (just the <form> html code). The javascript code is generating only a part of the form inputs or all of the form inputs?

Comment: the form i use to select item code,location, etc. then after i click (+) button,the data will show in table and named as array (_using javascript code_) that will be post to database

Comment: Ok, can you add your code here http://jsfiddle.net/ so it will be easier for debug ?

Comment: i have  add my code here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/analuthfa/of1qe2f3/)

Comment: Using this code are you able to add new rows in the table when clicking on 'Item' button ?